# Spring Security login programmatically (AuthenticationSuccessHandler)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring-security 3.2.6 and during testing I programmatically login my users with

```
public User login(User user) {
    logOut();
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
            authenticationToken);
    return user;
}
```

doing it in that way I notice that isn't going through the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to override the AuthenticationManager. When you want to override AuthentitionSeccessHandler then you need to

Override the AuthenticationFilter.

Authentication filter checks if the incoming request needs authentication, if Yes then calls the Authentication Manager to authenticate the request .
Authentication Manager authenticates request and add it to SecurityContextHolder and returns the Authrntication token which is dy default UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.

Filter then checks if there is a SuccessHandler defined. If yes then redirects the request to  the AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: well, it's not really override, more step over (was what I understood from your explanation)... there is a way to use the AuthenticationFilter?